# Ceasar cipher java codin gproblem

Tags: java

I have created a code for a caesar cipher with the shift being 25 characers. My code is not encoding the first half of the alphabet, but it is encoding the second half. I don't know why please help.

As an example, if I try to encode **"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"**, it comes out as **"abcdefghijklmmlkjihgfedcba"**. As you can see, Only the second half of the alphabet is encoded. What should i do for it to work and encode the second half?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        //creating alphabet and coded alphabet arrays
        char alphabet[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' '};
        char codedAlphabet[] = {'z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a',' '};

        //prompting user for encoding or decoding, and for the message
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the message: ");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        s.toLowerCase();
        StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer( s );

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to encode message, 2 to decode message: ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            encode(message, alphabet, codedAlphabet);
            System.out.println(message);
        } else if(choice == 2) {

        }

    }
    //method for encoding
    public static void encode(StringBuffer message, char a[], char b[]){
        for(int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
                if( message.charAt(i) == a[j]){
                    message.setCharAt(i, b[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: add `break;` after `message.setCharAt(i, b[j]);`

Comment: Btw, your `s.toLowercase();` line doesn't do what you maybe think it does.

Comment: And the coded alphabet is not a Caesar cipher of alphabet, since it is basically just reversed.

Comment: I think this is an example but is a Caesar cipher

Comment: @AndyTurner What does the lowercase method do? I thought it sets all of the characters to lowercase

Comment: @IlyaBursov Thank you very much

Comment: @ShashankSaini try printing `s` before and after that line (include uppercase letters in the input, ofc).

Answer (score 0):

Your check for finding the right character is correct. But when you replace the character you have to break that inner loop. Otherwise you keep replacing the same character position more than once if the selected encryption pairing fits. In this case you replace your first character `a` to `z`, which is correct, but then replace this new character `z` again (back to `a`), which is wrong.

```
public static void encode(StringBuffer message, char a[], char b[]){
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
            if( message.charAt(i) == a[j]){
                message.setCharAt(i, b[j]);
                // we found the character and replaced it, we
                // are done with this position, get to the next "i"
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your question code, I think this will be the answer.

```
public static void encode(StringBuffer message, char a[], char b[]){
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
            if( message.charAt(i) == a[j]){
                message.setCharAt(i, b[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void decode(StringBuffer message, char a[], char b[]){
    for(int i = 0; i<message.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<a.length; j++){
            if(  message.charAt(i) == b[j]){
                message.setCharAt(i, a[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```